# Javadoc inheritance from Maven dependency

Tags: maven, inheritance, javadoc

I need to inherit Javadoc from an interface that lives in a Maven dependency.  To inherit the documentation, I added an override to the javadoc plugin in my module. I put it in the `<reporting>` section of my POM because I want to generate the Javadoc as part of the `mvn site` goal.

My issue is that turning `<includeDependencySources>` on means, that the source for the dependencies specified are generated as part of the Javadoc for my module, which is not desired. Is there a way to inherit documentation from a dependency source without generating the Javadoc for the dependency source?

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration combine.self="append">
                <source>${jdkVersion}</source>
                <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>
                <includeTransitiveDependencySources>false</includeTransitiveDependencySources>
                <dependencySourceIncludes>
                    <dependencySourceInclude>com.mysource.object:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                    <dependencySourceInclude>com.mysource.object2:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                    <dependencySourceInclude>com.mysource.common:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                </dependencySourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: An amendment: In `mvn site` the `site` is not a goal but a _phase_ of [Maven's Site Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) (though the default binding to this phase is the `site` goal of the `maven-site-plugin` abbreviated with, you guessed it, `site`.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any clue that this is possible on the Maven Site Plugin's pages.

However, see [Apache Maven Site Plugin / FAQ, How do I Integrate static (X)HTML pages into my Maven site?](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/faq.html#How_do_I_Integrate_static_XHTML_pages_into_my_Maven_site):

> You can integrate your static pages by following these steps:
>
> - Put your static pages in the resources directory, `${basedir}/src/site/resources`
> - Create your `site.xml` and put it in `${basedir}/src/site`
> - Link to the static pages by modifying the menu section, create items and map them to the filenames of the static pages